# Why v-model attribute behaves differently

Tags: vue.js, v-model

Two equal examples (according to [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)) work differently:

First

```
<input v-model="value" @input.once="setDirty" type="text" id="object-email">
```

Second:

```
<input v-bind:value="value" v-on:input="value = $event.target.value"
                   @input.once="setDirty"
                   type="text"
                   id="object-email">
```

In the first example *value* changes only after second input, while the second example works correctly.
If we delete *@input.once* attribute, two examples will work fine.

P.S. Vue 2.4.0

Comment: Isn't the [.once modifier removed/deprecated](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#once-and-sync-Modifiers-on-v-bind-removed) in vue2?

Comment: @user1585345 No, according to Vue 2 [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers), not Vue 1

Answer (score 0):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6552#event-1246134893) that was fixed in version [2.4.3](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.4.3).

As a workaround for previous versions, you can simply use `@keydown.once="setDirty"` instead of `@input.once`.